# Tailing few lines from huge logs of kubectl logs -f

Tags: kubernetes, tail, kubectl

`kubectl logs -f pod` shows all logs from the beginning and it becomes a problem when the log is huge and we have to wait for a few minutes to get the last log. Its become more worst when connecting remotely. Is there a way that we can tail the logs for the last 100 lines of logs and follow them?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

In a cluster best practices are to gather all logs in a single point through an aggregator and analyze them with a dedicated tool. For that reason in K8S, log command is quite basic.

Anyway `kubectl logs -h` shows some options useful for you:

```
# Display only the most recent 20 lines of output in pod nginx
kubectl logs --tail=20 nginx

# Show all logs from pod nginx written in the last hour
kubectl logs --since=1h nginx
```

Some tools with your requirements (and more) are available on github, some of which are:

- https://github.com/boz/kail
- https://github.com/stern/stern

Comment: also `--timestamps` is helpful if you need logs with timestamps

Comment: New to this stuff, are there any official recommendations for how to aggregate the logs?

Comment: fluentd, logstash, look in google for other.

Comment: Is there a way to view the start of the logs? Like `--head=50` would show me the first 50 lines of the logs? I did run `kubectl logs -h` to see all options but couldn't find one that returns the head of logs.

Answer (score 46):

Try `kubectl logs -f pod --tail=10`

Answer (score 12):

To fetch tail lines from logs of a pod with multi containers.

```
kubectl logs <pod name> --all-containers=true --tail=10
```

To fetch tail lines from logs of  pods within an application:

```
kubectl logs --selector app=<your application> --tail=10
```

(ex:if your application has 3 pods then output of above command can be 30 logs 10 of each pod logs)

Answer (score 9):

You can ues this way to get the first 10 lines

```
kubectl logs my-pod-name  -n my-ns | head -n 10
```

Comment: They are looking for the last 100 lines, not the first lines

Answer (score -1):

You can also follow logs from the end if you are testing something:

```
kubectl logs my-pod-name --follow
```

This will work just like running `tail -f` in bash or other shells.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question and results in the same problem for large logs. You should consider removing this answer, else it will get down voted